# Laravel 5.2 ModelFactory Unexpected Result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel ModelFactory to automatically generate dummy data to be inserted to my database but I notice some unexpected result. Here is my pastebin of my [ModelFactory](http://laravel.io/bin/6LKPD) and the result.

And this is my pastebin of [expected result](http://laravel.io/bin/zj2Yv).

Comment: Are you getting any kind of errors?

Comment: My bad. It is just showing 25 result because I limit it in phpmyadmin.